# Template function with template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I want to create a factory, that returns `AVLNode`, if `BinaryTree` is `AVLTree`, and `Node` if the tree is not AVL. I have following code:

```
#include "BinaryTree.h"
#include "AVLTree.h"

class NodeFactory {

public :
    template <class T>
    static Node<T>* getNode(BinaryTree<T>* tree);
};

template <class T>
Node<T>* NodeFactory::getNode(BinaryTree<T>* tree) {
    if (tree->isAVL()) {
        return new AVLNode<T>();
    } else {
        return new Node<T>();
    }
}

UPD: (this is BinaryTree.h) 
template <class T> class Node;

template <class T> class BinaryTree {

public:

BinaryTree() {
    _isAVL = false;
    root = new Node<T>();
}

bool isAVL() {
    return _isAVL;
}

private:
    T elem;
    Node<T>* root;
    bool _isAVL;
};

template <class T> class Node {

public:
    Node() {
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
    }

    T get() {
        return elem;
    }

    void setRight(const T elem) {
        right = new Node<T>();
        right->set(elem);
    }

    void setLeft(const T elem) {
        left = new Node<T>();
        left->set(elem);
    }

private:
        T elem;
        Node* left;
        Node* right;
};
```

I removed almost all methods to make code more readable.

Now i have this error during compilation: "expected initializer before '<' token". Also Qt do not highlights  in Node, but highlights  in BinaryTree

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Oh, i deleted question while editing

Comment: "expected initializer before '<' token" in what line?

Answer (score 1):

It's a syntax error. You need

```
template <class T> // or <typename T>
Node<T>* NodeFactory::getNode(BinaryTree<T>* tree) {
```

Comment: So just typename instead of class?

Comment: `typename` and `class` can be used interchangebly (unless you've got template template parameter). You're missing the whole template specifier.

Comment: Hmm, now compiler tells me that expected initializer before '<' token. And Qt do not highlights <T> in Node<T>, but highlights <T> in BinaryTree<T>

Comment: @SemyonDanilov That's got something to do with definitions of `Node` or `BinaryTree`, probably. Can't help more without those.

Comment: @jrok i just added them